# delete group chat history from openfire(xmpp) server by smack

Tags: java, xmpp, openfire, smack

I am a newbie in XMPP (openfire). I am making an app which needs to delete group chat history from a particular group.

I googled but can't find anything like this. Is it even possible? If so, then how? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

When sending available presence to the group, you can set the MaxStanzas to 0, to avoid getting old group messages

```
Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
presence.setTo(roomJID);

//Setting MaxStanzas to 0
MUCInitialPresence m = new MUCInitialPresence();
History h = new History();
h.setMaxStanzas(0);
m.setHistory(h);
presence.addExtension(m);

try {
    connection.sendStanza(presence);
} catch (NotConnectedException e) {
}
```

Comment: yes i know that. But project is little different. It is not about sending text messages but sending coordinates. so i need to delete the cordinates after a successful conversation

Comment: @sovon Did you figured a way out? Thanks